# Trying to integrate Apple Singin in Flutter App for Web Version

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, apple-sign-in

I am trying to integrate apple sign in flutter app for web platform. But it does not work and says following error

Flutter App on Web (Tried Apple Sign In) Error

[image]

I tried to use https://pub.dev/packages/sign_in_with_apple
done with Apple Account integration as it is working in IPHONE & MAC, already.
But not working on web. Is there any extra integration required?

Comment: have you done setup for web too? can you add the process you did for web integration?